# using bind with member function

Tags: c++, c++11

Why are both `bind` versions compiling and working without problems, even though I'm using different parameter types in each call?

1. version 1 -> parameter foo vs.
2. version 2 -> parameter address of foo

I'd expected version 1 to produce a compile error...

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class Test   
{   
public:
   bool doSomething(){ std::cout << "xxx"; return true;};   
};

int main() {

Test foo;

// Version 1 using foo
std::function<bool(void)> testFct = std::bind(&Test::doSomething, foo);

// Version 2 using &foo
std::function<bool(void)> testFct2 = std::bind(&Test::doSomething, &foo);

testFct();
testFct2();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Becasue you can call a member function on both an object and pointer to an object?

Comment: duplicate answers my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::function<bool(void)> testFct = std::bind(&Test::doSomething, foo);
```

This will bind to a *copy* of `foo`, and call the function as `copy.doSomething()`. Beware that this will be wrong if you're expecting the function to be called on `foo` itself.

```
std::function<bool(void)> testFct2 = std::bind(&Test::doSomething, &foo);
```

This will bind to a *pointer* to `foo` and call the function as `pointer->doSomething()`. Beware that this will be wrong if `foo` has been destroyed before calling the function.

> I'd expected version 1 to produce a compile error...

You could disallow this behaviour by making `Test` uncopyable, if you wanted.